# How would I characterize ${\rm Gal}(\Bbb Q(ζ_{24})/\Bbb Q(i))$ up to isomorphism?

Tags: galois-theory

How would I characterize ${\rm Gal}(\Bbb Q(ζ_{24})/\Bbb Q(i))$ up to isomorphism where $ζ_{24}$ is a twenty fourth root of unity and ${\rm Gal}(\Bbb Q(ζ_{24})/\Bbb Q(i))$ is the corresponding Galois group?

Answer (score 2):

Well $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_{24})/\mathbb Q)$ is isomorphic to the multiplicative group $(\mathbb Z/24\mathbb Z)^\times$, which is isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z)^3$.
Therefore, the group $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_{24})/\mathbb Q(i))$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z)^3$ of order 4.
What does a subgroup like this have to look like?

Answer (score 2):

Let $G=Gal(Q(\zeta_{24}/Q)=Z_{24}^*\cong Z_2^3$.

The subgroup of $G$ of order 4 you want is obtained as the kernel $K$ of a homomorphism to $M=Gal(Q(i)/Q)\cong Z_2$ .

The non-trivial element of $M$ is complex conjugation.

The group $G$ has elements $g_k: \zeta_{24}\rightarrow \zeta_{24}^k$ for $k$ relatively prime to 24; $g_{23}$ is afforded by complex conjugation.  The kernel $K$ has the elements which act trivially on $i=\zeta_{24}^6$. So these are multiples of 6, say $6k$, which are 6 mod 24; that is $k=1\mod 4$,

so $K=\{g_1, g_5, g_{13}, g_{17}\}\cong Z_2^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Since

$$\operatorname{Gal}\left(\Bbb Q(\zeta_{24})/\Bbb Q\right)\cong\left(\Bbb Z/24\Bbb Z\right)^*\cong \left(\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z\right)^*\times \left(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\right)^*\cong (C_2\times C_2)\times C_2\cong (C_2)^3$$

and

$$8=[\Bbb Q(\zeta_{24}):\Bbb Q]=[\Bbb Q(\zeta_{24}):\Bbb Q(i)][\Bbb Q(i):\Bbb Q]=$$

we thus need a subgroup of order 2 in the above...

Comment: Is the subgroup just C2?

Comment: Well, isomorphic to: going with the isomorphisms I wrote above, it could as well be one of $\,C_2\times\{1\}\times\{1\}\cong \{1\}\times C_2\times\{1\}\cong\{1\}\times\{1\}\times C_2\,$ . Once you have this one, you have to take *the quotient* of the Galois group by it to get the group of the extension you want, according to Galois Correspondence theorem.

Comment: how would one going about actually taking the quotient of the Galois group?